# Where can i get the standalone parts of jQuery Mobile?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

Is there a place (website) where I can the the standalone parts of [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)? I'm interested in the [radiobutton](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/forms/forms-radiobuttons.html).

I don't want to use jQuery Mobile as I'm already using jQTouch.

Comment: I noticed you are linking to the Alpha 4.1 documentation for jQuery Mobile. If you are using Alpha then seriously think about upgrading to 1.0. Here is the 1.0 version of the link you posted: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/forms/radiobuttons/

Comment: I'm not using jQuery Mobile at all, I just want the radiobutton, standalone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQM is now decoupled:

- http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/08/03/jquery-mobile-beta-2-released/

> **Widgets: Now decoupled for flexible builds**
>
> We’ve wanted to decouple all our widgets from the page plugin for a
>   long time now and we’re happy to announce that we finally landed this
>   change. So what exactly does decoupled mean anyway? Well, the
>   individual widgets and utilities have always been broken out into
>   separate script files. However, the page plugin was responsible for
>   handling the auto-initialization all of the official plugins found in
>   the markup at page creation. This situation made it impossible to
>   remove plugins you don’t need without causing errors, and generally
>   set a bad precedent for future widget additions.
>
> Now, pretty much all the UI widgets in the jQuery Mobile library are
>   completely decoupled so they can simply be deleted if not needed for a
>   particular project. This change allows you to dramatically reduce the
>   size of the library by only including the specific set of widgets or
>   features you need, in addition to the handful of required, core files.
>   While we still plan to do more decoupling and cleanup, the following
>   files are now decoupled and can safely be removed from the make file
>   before you do a custom build:
>
> - page header/content/footer
> - collapsible
> - controlgroup
> - fieldcontain
> - fixheaderfooter
> - button
> - checkboxradio
> - select
> - slider
> - textinput
> - links theming
> - listview
> - navbar
> - grid
>
> We will work on a dependency map because a few widgets rely on others
>   to work. For example, the button markup plugin is called by many of
>   the widgets above, so it can only be excluded but if you’re not using
>   any of the widgets that depend on buttons.
>
> We’re still working out our recommendations for mapping plugin
>   dependencies and decoupling things even further. Ultimately, this will
>   be surfaced in a download builder tool, so stay tuned!

You can head over to their GIT Repo and just download what you want:

- https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/tree/master/js

Comment: Have you got a concrete example of what I have to download when i want to make a radiobutton? Thanks for the good answer!

Comment: Even with this, it's kinda hard to know what to include to get only one widget...

Comment: jQM Did mention a Download Builder in Alpha on the latest blog post: http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/04/13/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-1-0/ Not sure if it's out yet but you can email the developer and ask to be a part of this at: todd@filamentgroup.com