# Stand-Alone jQuery Mobile Widgets with Minimal JS and CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'd like to use some components of JQM in my non-JQM responsive web site, without breaking any existing styles and only downloading the **minimum** JS/CSS I need.

I've read [Any way to use jQuery mobile widgets independently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188429/any-way-to-use-jquery-mobile-widgets-independently) and [Where can i get the standalone parts of jQuery Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620735/where-can-i-get-the-standalone-parts-of-jquery-mobile). I've seen a lot of Fiddles, but they all include the complete jquery mobile js and css. (I don't want the entire CSS because it breaks my existing site CSS and I prefer a minimal JavaScript download for performance - important on mobile devices).

After using the http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/ and getting my download, it's unclear how to invoke JQM, or what order scripts need to be placed in order to get the widget working. Do I need to use this in conjunction with regular jQuery?

Does anyone have any instructions how to get only one widget working without the entire framework?

Answer (score 1):

I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/31844001/1620112, answered by the (masterful) Omar, but the question doesn't seem very popular - maybe because it's too specific - so I'm going to generalize and answer it myself.

Yes. You need jQuery. Load that first.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Next, load the 1 JS and 2 CSS files you downloaded from the Download Builder.

```
<script src="jquery.mobile.custom.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.custom.structure.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.custom.theme.css" />
```

Finally, invoke the widget as Omar suggests here https://stackoverflow.com/a/31844001/1620112

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $(".ui-collapsible-set").collapsibleset();
});
</script>
```

Customize your look in jquery.mobile.custom.theme.css. You've got widgets!